# How to get rid of the vertical space after mdframed?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
The beginning,
  \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt,rightmargin=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt]
  Hello, world!
  \end{mdframed}
and the end.
\end{document}
```

There is no empty vertical space before the red rectangle, but there is one after it. How to get rid of it?

Please, assume that I can only control what's going on till the `\end{mdframed}`. The content after it is out of my control (I'm making a command for a package).

Comment: don't use mdframed. It is old and unmaintained. Use tcolorbox instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how would you do this with `tcolorbox`?

Comment: by checking the documentation. It has lots of keys to adjust all things. E.g. `\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=red,beforeafter skip balanced=0pt]` suppresses the spaces before and after.

Comment: As far as I can see, the setting of `skipbelow` happens after `\begin{mdframed}`, so the value is set inside a group, but the skip is used when the group has already ended, so the value is *always* equal to `\topsep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is a bug in `mdframed`.

What happens is that `skipbelow=0pt` is evaluated when the `\begin{mdframed}` group has started, but then

```
\addvspace\mdf@skipbelow@length
```

is executed when the group has already ended, so the value is restored to what it was at the beginning, namely `\topsep`.

You actually need to jump over two levels of grouping.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{bugfix}
\AtEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
  \stepcounter{bugfix}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname bugfix@\thebugfix\endcsname{%
    \mdf@skipbelow@length=\the\mdf@skipbelow@length\relax
  }%
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\expandafter\aftergroup\csname bugfix@\thebugfix\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The beginning,
\begin{mdframed}[
  linecolor=red,
  linewidth=1pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=3pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt
]
Hello, world!
\end{mdframed}
and the end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to make it work, but it breaks when I use `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}` for some reason.

Comment: I just had this same issue. I fixed it by putting \hrule height0pt at the bottom of the mdframed environment.

Answer (score -1):

Added `\vspace` You can get rid of the vertical space after mdframed, is it
good solution for You?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
The beginning,
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt,rightmargin=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt]
Hello, world!
\end{mdframed}
\vspace{-9pt}
and the end.
\end{document}
```

One more example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
 The beginning,\\   
 \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\parbox{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep- 
 2\fboxrule}{%
 Hello, world!}}
 and the end.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but the problem is that the space of `-9pt` is hardcoded. Can you make it more environment-dependent? Maybe rely on `\parskip`?

Comment: I have edited something, now better?

Comment: I need `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`